# Protocol Buffer C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm new to Protocol Buffers. I'm wondering about the protocol buffer compiler. How to install / use it to convert .proto files into .cs files.

The README instructions says, To install, simply place this binary somewhere in your PATH. What exactly is the PATH? For reference, I've been trying to follow the example here...https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial#compiling-your-protocol-buffers.

Whenever I try to run the .exe I see a small window pop up then it quickly disappears...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: That's a command line utility.  You need to run it with parameters from a command prompt.

Comment: The [PATH](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) is an environment variable, pretty easy to Google that one!

Answer (score 0):

First you put your folder of 32 or 64 at the folder C:/ , then you copy your path in the bin folder to the Environment Variables:

https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/